# Drawing on html canvas through javascript/jquery, how do I fix this mouse x/y glitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, draw

I've been searching for an answer to this question all over and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

This is a first-try on doing something like this in my free time so that I can use what I learn to build an actual tool for my company to use.

The code being referenced is on github, here: [My Github Repo](https://github.com/BenDevPlusPlus/mapDraw)
Sorry I don't have it hosted anywhere for live testing. If someone knows where I can put it to answer this question easier please let me know.

In any case, it creates a canvas, uses javascript to draw a map image scaled to the canvas, and draws a rectangle when you click in the canvas. But for some reason, I can't figure out why the rectangles are not drawn right on the cursor unless you click on 0,0. There's some kind of additive offset the further right or down you click. I've tried examining the event data in the console and searching everywhere online for what could be causing it but I have no idea.

If you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code from your github repo in your question? The Stack Overflow policy is that questions and answers should be as self sufficient as possible and only use external sources when unavoidable.

Comment: My bad for writing a bad question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are scaling the canvas in CSS, so its coordinates are no longer matching screen coordinates.

When changing the CSS to

```
canvas {
  width: 800px;  /* same as the HTML attribute */
  height: 600px; /* same as the HTML attribute */
}
```

the coordinate calculation can be done with this:

```
var posx = e.pageX - position.left, posy = e.pageY - position.top;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was such a silly beginner mistake on my part! Really appreciate your help even though I asked a rule-breaking question.